# Cadence IUS simulator options

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, cadence, questasim, synopsys-vcs

What is the difference between -INcdir and +incdir+ options in NC simulator?

Below is the example command from the Makefile. As far as I know the testbench directories are included using **-INcdir** and  the source code file directories are included using **+incdir+** command

```
ncvlog -SV -INcdir ../include -INcdir ../src -64bit ../src/top.sv ../src/test.sv;
ncelab ncelab.log top +incdir+../../../sv/src +incdir+../../../sv/include
```

Please help me to understand the the significance of these options.

Comment: Testbench files are also source code files.

Comment: @TudorTimi Yes , but testbench files won’t be encrypted like the BFM or Monitor files, so I described these as source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Tudor. They actually mean the same thing.

The +incdir+*arg* is replaced with ncvlog -incdir *arg*, the same way in which +define+*arg* is replaced with ncvlog -define *arg*.

It is referred to as "Plus" option translation in the Cadence NC-Verilog Simulator user guide.

[image: Snapshot from user guide]

Answer (score 1):

They both mean the same thing. The original Verilog simulator used arguments of the type `+incdir+` to specify include paths. The options still exist for legacy reasons. You'll notice other tools also provide `+incdir+`, for the same reason.